# Remove whitespace in HAML in if statement

Tags: css, ruby, haml

I am trying to have `Account | Login` if user isn't signed in, and `Account | Logout` if they are signed in. The code is:

```
.nav.right
 %h3
  Account &#124;
    - if user_signed_in?
      = link_to "Log out", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete, class: "nav"
    - else
      = link_to "Log in", new_user_session_path, class: "nav"
```

All I can seem to do is:

```
Account |

Login
```

I found how to remove whitespace in HAML around links, but it does not work for me because my link is in an if statement. I tried to put `%span` before the links, tried using the `<` and `>` as shown [here](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#whitespace_removal__and_).

Does anyone have any idea how I can get around this?

**EDIT**

the css for the .nav.right is:

```
.nav.right {
float:right;
}
```

Comment: Seems like CSS specific problem (not HTML). Try to investigate it use Browser Developer Tools. Probably you don't have free space in parent element to place all your links in one line.

Comment: you don't need to remove extra spaces. in html one space is essentially the same as any number of spaces (incl. \n \t).

Comment: @iced, then how do I get the link onto the same line as the "account |" ??

Comment: @maxd I checked that and it didn't make a difference

Comment: not enough info in your question. I'm just telling you that `<a...> <a...>` is the same as `<a...> LOTS OF SPACES AND NEWLINES HERE <a...>`.

Comment: What more information do you need then?

Comment: Please show us your class’ `nav` css. I bet there is smth like `clear: left` or `display: block`.

Comment: please see edited version with css